# Dancing behavior of a droplet

Tags: experimental-physics

When a small droplet is dropped on a extremely hot surface (at around $220^\circ C$), it shows a dancing behavior by moving around fast on the surface. What is the concept behind this [bizarre behavior of droplet on a hot surface](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/UnimportantKindAsianconstablebutterfly-size_restricted.gif)?

[image]

Comment: The [Leidenfrost Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect)?